# Mongoose update model and "pre" methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want update a model, y use "findByIdAndUpdate" function to update a single document. I put a pre("validate") in schema, but this only fires when use save() or when I create, not when i update.

I'm using this for push nested object, and i need check some params each pushed document, but if i use save all pre("validates") that i have in other nested object will fire.

```
var update = {...};
User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, update, callback);
```

Some idea?

Comment: That's correct.  Mongoose middleware only fires on `save` and `create` and not on any of the `update` methods which are passed directly through to the driver after casting.

Comment: Yes, but how i can flow CRUD operations in code if i have some nested objects and i only want validate the new data in new push object.

Comment: You'll likely have to duplicate your validation checking outside of the schema for the `update` case.  Yep, it's messy and awkward.